# how to list all to be merged files or all merge commits

Tags: git, merge, gitlab

I'm trying to list all new files that are to be merged while a merge request is created. With the following piece of code I'm able to get all files but only from the last commit:

```
script {
    def commitedFiles = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r ${gitlabMergeRequestLastCommit}")       
    if (commitedFiles.contains(".sql")) {
        println "[INFO] Adding merge request comment..."
        addGitLabMRComment comment: "Merge commit contains SQL files."
    }
    else {
        println "[INFO] No SQL files found in the merge commit. Omitting..."
    }
}
```

However if there are more then one merge commit I cannot check if there are files to be merged that are not supposed to be.

Is there a way to list all the yet to be merged files or at least get all the merge commits (that are visible in 'Commits' tab in a merge request in Gitlab) in order to loop through them and get all the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the list of files modified "since current forked from target branch", use :

```
git diff --name-only [upstream branch]...[current branch]   # 3 dots

# for example :
git diff --name-only origin/main...origin/feature
```

---

For reference : this behavior is documented in the initial paragraph of [`git help diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgtltcommitgtltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203)

> `git diff A...B` is equivalent to `git diff $(git merge-base A B) B`. You can omit any one of `<commit>`, which has the same effect as using `HEAD` instead.

and `git merge-base A B` is the most recent fork point between `A` and `B`.

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly fine. One follow up question: is it possible to get only files that are newly added excluding the modified ones?

Comment: look at `--diff-filter` in `git diff` options. You may want to also add `--no-renames` if you want to avoid files being detected as `R`enamed rather than `A`dded.

Comment: '--diff-filter=[A]' does the trick. Thanks a lot!